# How to make user defined functions for binned_statistic

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I am using scipy stats package to take statistics along the an axis, but I am having trouble taking the percentile statistic using `binned_statistic`.  I have generalized the code below, where I am trying taking the 10th percentile of a dataset with x, y values within a series of x bins, and it fails.

I can of course do function options, like median, and even the numpy standard deviation using `np.std`.  However, I cannot figure out how to use `np.percentile` because it requires 2 arguments (e.g. `np.percentile(y, 10)`), but then it gives me a `ValueError: statistic not understood` error.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as scist

y_median = scist.binned_statistic(x,y,statistic='median',bins=20,range=[(0,5)])[0]

y_std = scist.binned_statistic(x,y,statistic=np.std,bins=20,range=[(0,5)])[0]

y_10 = scist.binned_statistic(x,y,statistic=np.percentile(10),bins=20,range=[(0,5)])[0]

print y_median
print y_std
print y_10
```

I am at a loss and have even played around with user defined functions like this, but with no luck:

```
def percentile10():
   return(np.percentile(y,10))
```

Any help, is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with the function you defined is that it takes no arguments at all! It needs to take a `y` argument that corresponds to your sample, like this:

```
def percentile10(y):
   return(np.percentile(y,10))
```

You could also use a `lambda` function for brevity:

```
scist.binned_statistic(x, y, statistic=lambda y: np.percentile(y, 10), bins=20,
                       range=[(0, 5)])[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, the lambda function works!  I transposed my percentile function wrong to my post, and did have the argument in there, and it still didn't work.  But, problem solved!