# Binned statistics with irregular and alternating bins

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, binning

This is a short, complete example of a more complex real-world application.

**Libraries used**:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats as scist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import zip_longest
```

**Data**:

I have an array with irregular bins defined with start and end, for example like these (**in the real-world case this format is a given as it is the output of another process**):

```
bin_starts = np.array([0, 93, 184, 277, 368])
bin_ends = np.array([89, 178, 272, 363, 458])
```

which I combine with:

```
bns = np.stack(zip_longest(bin_starts, bin_ends)).flatten()
bns
>>> array([  0,  89,  93, 178, 184, 272, 277, 363, 368, 458])
```

giving a regularly alternating sequence of long and short intervals, all of irregular length.
This is a sketched representation of the given long and short intervals:
[image: Bins_sketch]

I have a bunch of time series data, similar to the random data created below:

```
# make some random example data to bin
np.random.seed(45)
x = np.arange(0,460)
y = 5+np.random.randn(460).cumsum()
plt.plot(x,y);
```

[image: Data to bin]

**Objective**:

I would like to use the sequence of intervals to collect statistics (mean, percentiles, *etcetera*) on the data -  but only using the long intervals, i.e. the yellow ones in the sketch.

**Assumptions and clarifications:**

The edges of long intervals never overlap; in other words, there is always a short interval in between long intervals. Also, the first interval is always a long one.

**Current solution:**

One way to do it is to use `scipy.stats.binned_statistic` on all intervals and then slice the result to only keep every other one (i.e. `[::2]`), like this (a great help for some statistics, like `np.percentile`, was reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159976/1034648) by [@ali_m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461210/ali-m)):

```
ave = scist.binned_statistic(x, y, 
                         statistic = np.nanmean, 
                         bins=bns)[0][::2]
```

which gives me the desired result:

```
plt.plot(np.arange(0,5), ave);
```

[image: binned_data]

**Question**:
Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this (using any of `Numpy`, `Scipy` or `Pandas`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using some combo of `IntervalIndex`, `pd.cut`, `groupby`, and `agg` is a relatively straightforward and easy way to get what you want.

I'd first make the DataFrame (not sure if this is the best way to go from np arrays):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'], df['y'] = x, y
```

Then you can define your bins as a list of tuples:

```
bins = list(zip(bin_starts, bin_ends))
```

Use a pandas [IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.html), which has a `from_tuples()` method, to create bins to later use in `cut`. This is useful because you then don't have to rely on slicing your `bns` array to disentangle the "regularly alternating sequence of long and short intervals"-- Instead you can explicitly define the bins you are interested in:

```
ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(bins, closed='both')
```

The `closed` kwarg specifes whether to include the end member numbers in the interval. For example for the tuple `(0, 89)`, with `closed='both'` the interval will include both 0 and 89 (as opposed to `left`, `right`, or `neither`).

Then create a category column in the dataframe using [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), which is a method for binning values into intervals. An `IntervalIndex` object can be specified using the `bin` kwarg:

```
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.x, bins=ii)
```

Last, use `df.groupby()` and `.agg()` to get whatever stats you'd like:

```
df.groupby('bin')['y'].agg(['mean', np.std])
```

which outputs:

```
                 mean       std
bin                            
[0, 89]     -4.814449  3.915259
[93, 178]   -7.019151  3.912347
[184, 272]   7.223992  5.957779
[277, 363]  15.060402  3.979746
[368, 458]  -0.644127  3.361927
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As it happens, in the real-world case I have data in a Pandas DataFrame, but I decided to keep the small example more agnostic. Your solution looks neat, it works on small example (I get same plot as my last one with `plt.plot(np.arange(0,5), df.groupby('bin')['y'].agg(['mean', np.std]).loc[:, 'mean']);`),  happy to choose the answer once tested on real-world case. If you have time, would you expand it with more explanation of `pandas.IntervalIndex` and `pandas.cut` since Pandas can be a bit intimidating - and reference rather dry (even for non newbies, IMHO).

Comment: I think the key here is that `pandas.IntervalIndex` allows using tuples (defined by your `bins = list(zip(bin_starts, bin_ends))` for bin edges definition. Clever.